# Creating connectors using Pervasive Connectors

Tags: java, pervasive

Can any one please help me to over come my issue, i am searching how to create a connectors in pervasive from 1week, i am unable to find the solution, atleast step to move on, i followed the predefined link

```
http://www.pervasive.com/Galaxy/Products/Connectors.aspx?type=connector
```

Please help me, how to create a connector in java for pervasive database

Answer (score 1):

The connector frameworks and documentation are not publicly available and require a non-disclosure agreement.  You must contact Pervasive (http://www.pervasiveintegration.com) to discuss this.